# Attached and not inline email forwarding using EWS JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, exchangewebservices, office-addins

I would like to kindly ask for some support on forwarding an email **as attachment** and not inline using EWS JavaScript API.

Even though I am a complete newbie in this area, I did not want to post a question here before reading as much as I could on the topic. I have studied all the documentation I could get my hands on, from msdn, github samples, most of the questions here on Stackoverflow and up to dev.oulook documentation like:

https://dev.outlook.com/Samples/Addins

https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/

etc. and I could not find an answer to how to forward the current email selected from inbox as attachment and not inline (to a predefined email address).

What I tried:
- obtain the ItemId of the email 
- obtain the ChangeKey attribute for it 
- with these values try to forward the email in 2 ways:
1) create an email in drafts and try to update it by adding the selected email as attachment
2) Create a new email and add as attachment the email selected from inbox

option 1) did not work and I noticed the attachment operations are all for composing emails and not draft emails (strange one I guess .. but not my main concern)

option 2) with this sample code:

```
var soapToForwardItem = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
                '               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
                '               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
                '               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
                '               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
                '  <soap:Header>' +
                '    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />' +
                '  </soap:Header>' +
                '  <soap:Body>' +
                '    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">' +
                '      <m:Items>' +
                '        <t:ForwardItem>' +
                '          <t:ToRecipients>' + addressesSoap + '</t:ToRecipients>' +
                '          <t:ReferenceItemId Id="' + item_id + '" ChangeKey="' + changeKey + '" />' +
                '          <t:NewBodyContent BodyType="Text">' + comment + '</t:NewBodyContent>' +
                '        </t:ForwardItem>' +
                '      </m:Items>' +
                '    </m:CreateItem>' +
                '  </soap:Body>' +
                '</soap:Envelope>';
```

had unfortunately the result: a new email with the old one inline and not as attachment (I am interested to preserve the email header of the attached email for later access). 
I see there are examples where "inline" can be set to false for file attachments but not for item attachment.

Any constructive input or working code snippet would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!